# How can I load mysql data into jquery datatable in electon app

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, datatables, electron

I making an electron app using a localhost server with MySQL database and jquery `datatable` plugin. How do I load the data from MySQL databsae into the `datatable`?

I have been able to print the data from the database in the console, but I can't figure out how to populate the `datatable` using the data I have

index.html table

```
<section role="main" id="main">
        <div class="with-padding">
            <table class="table responsive-table" id="sorting-advanced">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"><input type="checkbox" name="check-all" id="check-all" value="1"></th>
                        <th scope="col">Text</th>
                        <th scope="col" width="15%" class="align-center hide-on-mobile">Date</th>
                        <th scope="col" width="15%" class="align-center hide-on-mobile-portrait">Status</th>
                        <th scope="col" width="15%" class="hide-on-tablet">Tags</th>
                        <th scope="col" width="60" class="align-center">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6">
                            6 entries found
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>

                <tbody>


                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" class="checkbox-cell"><input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" id="check-1" value="1"></th>
                        <td id="name"></td>
                        <td id="date"></td>
                        <td id="status">Enabled</td>
                        <td><small class="tag">User</small> <small class="tag">Client</small> <small class="tag green-bg">Valid</small></td>
                        <td class="low-padding align-center"><a href="#" class="button compact icon-gear">Edit</a></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>

    </section>
```

script for the datatable

```
  <script>
        var table = $('#sorting-advanced');
        table.dataTable({
            'aoColumnDefs': [{
                'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': [0, 5]
            }],
            'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
            'sDom': '<"dataTables_header"lfr>t<"dataTables_footer"ip>',
            'fnInitComplete': function(oSettings) {
                // Style length select
                table.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_length select').addClass('select blue-gradient glossy').styleSelect();
                tableStyled = true;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

preload.js

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function(err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        let name = [this is what am getting no][1]document.getElementById("name");
        let date = document.getElementById("date");
        let status = document.getElementById("status");

        console.log(result);


        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            name.innerHTML += result[i].name + "<br/>";
            date.innerHTML += result[i].address + "<br/>";
            status.innerHTML += "enable" + "<br/>";
        }
    });
});
```

I want to load all the data from the database in the `datatable`

[screenshot of what I'm getting now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e5mH.png)

[screenshot of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vke7.png)

Comment: Which technology do you want to use for this requirement? PHP or some other server-side language? Using jQuery alone, this might not be possible

Comment: I'm working in a node js environment, is there a way to work around the problem using JavaScript? if not,then how will I achieve this using PHP in electron app?Thanks

Comment: Where is your database located? On any server? Then it probably would be easier to use some server-side language for that

Comment: I'm using a localhost sever on my computer, XAMPP

Comment: I have edited my codes, I've been able to display them now, but all data are appearing in one table row. i have included screenshots of both what I'm getting and what I want to get.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've figured out how to achieve the result and it's working perfectly

html code

```
  <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped ">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Room Number</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Reg Number</th>
                                    <th>Program</th>
                                    <!-- <th>Img</th> -->
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tbdy">


                            </tbody>
                            <!-- 
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Position</th>
                                    <th>Office</th>
                                    <th>Age</th>
                                    <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot> -->
                        </table>
```

script

```
 <!--  DataTables.net Plugin, full documentation here: https://datatables.net/    -->
        <script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#datatable').DataTable({
                    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                    "lengthMenu": [
                        [5, 25, 50, -1],
                        [5, 25, 50, "All"]
                    ],
                    responsive: false,
                    language: {
                        search: "_INPUT_",
                        searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
                    }

                });

                var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();

                // Edit record
                table.on('click', '.edit', function() {
                    $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

                    var data = table.row($tr).data();
                    alert('You press on Row: ' + data[0] + ' ' + data[1] + ' ' + data[2] + '\'s row.');
                });

                // Delete a record
                table.on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
                    $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    table.row($tr).remove().draw();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                //Like record
                table.on('click', '.like', function() {
                    alert('You clicked on Like button');
                });
            });
        </script>
```

renderer script

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "mydb"
});
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query('SELECT * FROM customers', function(err, data) { 
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data.length)
        var tbdy = document.getElementById('tbdy');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            var td2 = document.createElement('td');
            var td3 = document.createElement('td');
            var td4 = document.createElement('td');
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].id));
            td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].name));
            td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].address));
            td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].img));
            tr.appendChild(td);
            tr.appendChild(td2);
            tr.appendChild(td3);
            tr.appendChild(td4);
            tbdy.appendChild(tr);
        }
    });
});
```